# Can you recover a deleted message or chain of messages from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mac, messages

I see all of these software that claim that they can recover messages deleted from your iPhone. Do they actually work? 
For example, if I received 2 text messages from my friend and I immediately deleted them. Is it possible to recover them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have done an iCloud backup before those messages have been deleted then you can bring them back from iCloud backup with a restore from iCloud.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there's a matter of fact you should not ignore: all the deleted messages will soon be overwritten randomly to make room for the new coming ones. If you really want to recover deleted messages from iPhone without backup, before you use any third party recovery software, you should turn on Airplane mode immediately to stop deleted messages getting overwritten.

By now some of those data recovery software do have an ability to recover deleted messages, but they can't be certain that their software can recover all your deleted messages. Some of them are free for try, like Gihosoft [iPhone Recovery](https://www.gihosoft.com/iphone-data-recovery-free.html), which you can test by yourself. Also you can find some user guide video like this on Youtude: https://youtu.be/n1thXApuo9c.

To avoid important messages or something else missing, I suggest you back up your iPhone regularly.